# what does "20,000 foot view" mean?

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-usage

I have just started reading a book on Unix and came across a sentence which says:

> Fig. shows the 20,000 foot view of the organization of the GNU/Linux Operating System.

What is meant by *the 20,000 foot view*? Is it a technical term? Or is it just English?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is specific to English. Viewing something from a very far point of view, we would be able to see the whole picture (or the big picture) much better.

Comment: It is just English and means "an overall or cursory look at something".

Comment: What you see of the landscape from the window of an airplane flying at an altitude of 20,000 feet.  You see the overall shape, but no details.

Comment: I hear terms like this a lot in my office. I'm sure the metaphor predates the book, but I think recent popularity of these terms probably stems from the [GTD philosophy](http://www.wikisummaries.org/Getting_Things_Done:_The_Art_of_Stress-Free_Productivity#Chapter_9_--_Doing:_Making_the_Best_Action_Choices), which has recently become fairly popular in the business world.

Comment: As an extra bit of information, I hear the version "10,000 foot view" more often than "20,000 foot view".

Comment: @DamkerngT. The distance is specifically altitude from a plane.

Comment: @Yen - Funny; the version I usually hear is _the 30,000 foot view_. I guess it depends on if you're thinking of a Cessna or an airliner in your metaphor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's an expression that means to see a thing in its entirety, as a whole. To assess the OS not by looking at how individual parts work, but "how the parts work together and as a whole." It's to see things in a broad view.

Comment: Of course, it's based on the analogy of looking out the window of an airplane at (roughly) cruising altitude.

Comment: @Wayne Actually, typical cruising altitude of passenger planes is 30-40,000ft. The  choice of 20,000ft for this metaphor is a bit strange but, yes, it's obviously about aircraft.

Answer (score 2):

It means to see the big picture regardless of the minor details.

To see the over-riding view of the system, process, organization, etc. at a senior level.

Examples:

This class is tough but I remind myself of the 20,000 foot view of getting a degree at the end!

The new CEO looked at the 20,000 foot view of the customer support process and its impact on the company and decided to bring it in-house."